# Assistance in properly scripting a Join and Un-Join Domain script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting, powershell-4.0

Hello guys i have started to create a script that would basically automate the un-join and joining of a computer via a script this initially works fine right up until the point i need to start pinging for the computer to come back online. For the instance of un-joining it works fine but all the issue arise when trying to join.

Maybe fresh pair of eyes can lend me some Intel on the matter thank you.

```
    <#
############################################################################################################
# Written by CPineda                             #  NOTE: This only works if computer is on the wire.      #
# This Script un-joins and re-joins the domain.  #        So its very important that we connect the devce  #
# Created: 04/27/2016                            #        to the LAN.                                      #
# Last revision 4/6/2016                         #                                                         #
############################################################################################################
#>

# Set up your Variables
$ComputerIP = "" #Stores the Computers IP
$ComputerName = "" #Stores the Name of the computer you will be working with.
#$LocalCredentials = "" #Stores the Local Administrator credentials. (As Neeeded)
$DomainCredentials = "" #Stores the Domain Administrator credentials.

# Get information needed for the script to run.
while ($ComputerIP -eq ""){

    Clear-Host #Clear the PS Console Window
    $ComputerIP = Read-Host "Enter the name of the Computer IP"
}

while ($ComputerName -eq ""){

    Clear-Host #Clear the PS Console Window
    $ComputerName = Read-Host "Enter the name of the Computer" 
}

<# while ($LocalCredentials -eq ""){

    Clear-Host #Clear the PS Console Window
    $LocalCredentials = Read-Host "Enter the User name of the Local User Admin Account"    
}
#> 

while ($DomainCredentials -eq ""){

    Clear-Host #Clear the PS Console Window
    $DomainCredentials = Read-Host "Enter the User name of the Domain User Admin Account"    
}
# Remove the computer from the Domain.
Remove-Computer -ComputerName $ComputerName -LocalCredential $ComputerName\administrator -UnJoinDomainCredential kelsonfla\$DomainCredentials -WorkgroupName WORKGROUP -Force -Restart

Read-Host "Hit ENTER to continue"

# Ping until computer returns on the wire.
Clear-Host
Write-Host "At this time we will ping the compputer in question untill it returns back online"
Write-Host "Hit ENTER to continue"
Read-Host

Test-Connection ($ComputerIP) {
        $result = Test-Connection $ComputerIP -Count 3 -Delay 10 -Quiet
        if ($Result | where { $_ -match 'Reply from ' }){$true} 
        else {$false}
}       
        Write-Verbose "The computer $ComputerIP has went down for a reboot. Waiting for it to come back up..."
        while (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerIP)) {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
            Write-Verbose "Waiting for $ComputerIP to come back online"
}
        Write-Verbose "The computer $ComputerIP has come online. Waiting for OS to initialize"
        $EapBefore = $ErrorActionPreference
        $ErrorActionPreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::SilentlyContinue
        while (!(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerIP -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Credential $LocalCredentials)) {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
            Write-Verbose "Waiting for OS to initialize..."
        $ErrorActionPreference = $EapBefore
}

# Add computer back to the Domain.
Add-Computer -ComputerName $ComputerIP -LocalCredential $ComputerName\administrator -DomainName kelsonfla.local -Credential kelsonfla\$DomainCredentials -Restart -Force

Read-Host "Hit ENTER to continue"

# Ping until computer returns on the wire.
Clear-Host
Write-Host "At this time we will ping the compputer in question untill it returns back online"
Write-Host "Hit ENTER to continue"
Read-Host

Test-Connection ($ComputerIP) {
        $result = Test-Connection $ComputerIP -Count 3 -Delay 10 -Quiet
        if ($Result | where { $_ -match 'Reply from ' }){$true} 
        else {$false}
}       
        Write-Verbose "The computer $ComputerIP has went down for a reboot. Waiting for it to come back up..."
        while (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerIP)) {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
            Write-Verbose "Waiting for $ComputerIP to come back online"
}
        Write-Verbose "The computer $ComputerIP has come online. Waiting for OS to initialize"
        $EapBefore = $ErrorActionPreference
        $ErrorActionPreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::SilentlyContinue
        while (!(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerIP -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Credential $LocalCredentials)) {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
            Write-Verbose "Waiting for OS to initialize..."
        $ErrorActionPreference = $EapBefore
}

Clear-Host
Write-Output "If you are Reading this then you have successfully Unjoined and Re-Joined a Computer to the Network"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
Clear-Host
```

Comment: I recommend providing a short script that contains only the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the specific problem you're experiencing.

Comment: what is the actual response you get? or is it a situation where the while loop just goes on forever? Is there a GPO that is disabling the windows firewall that disappears and now you are dealing with a firewall problem trying to see the unjoined machine?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart problem is it will not show the ping requests or verbose commands at all. When it executes for the first time it goes through the whole process of authentication and it executes, and then when i hit enter for the pinging process nothing.

Comment: @ssaviers no it executes the fist part fine its the pinging process and executing the second part of the process i am having issues with. I think it may just be easier to create two separate scripts for this operation.

Comment: You already said it doesn't do _x_ or _y_. You're still asking someone to debug all of your code for you. Hence my suggestion: Start small, and you will begin to understand better what's not working.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart i appreciate your time and input.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart At this point right now it runs the first part flawlessly. The thing is i do not want to separate the process into two individual scripts. Hence why i ask for input from other coders so that they can make suggestions for noobs like me. I am self learning so, all of this really helps me so thanks again.

Comment: I must not be communicating my meaning very well...it is doubtful that someone is going to debug and fix your code for you. (If we do that, you're not learning anything!) Start small with code you _can_ understand, and build on that. That is a better way to learn than doing a "code dump" and asking others to fix it for you.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart im not asking for someone to fix it but require insight on how to make it run better. I have taken your advice and have broken the code into two parts right now, the first half is working just fine so i am in the process of making all run under one script. So i understand, in the past i have used Stackflow to get answers but i been noticing that the help here now comes which A LOT of critique which really does not bother me but only makes me question if i should use another site for Insights to learn,

Comment: There's a difference between asking for help with a _specific_ question and "here's my code, it doesn't work exactly how I want, what am I doing wrong" and posting a 100-line code dump. For the best help and your own understanding, post a _short_ example that contains _only_ the code that exhibits the problem. This is also called: [short, self-contained, correct example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart thanks again, i appreciate your time and education.

Answer (score 0):

**First** : for the ping part, you should remove the code :

```
Test-Connection ($ComputerIP) {
        $Result = ping $ComputerIP -n 3
        if ($Result | where { $_ -match 'Reply from ' }) {
            $true
        } else {
            $false
        }
}
```

and simply use

```
!$result = $false
do {
  Write-Verbose "Waiting for $ComputerIP to come back online"
  $result = Test-Connection $ComputerIP -Count 2 -Delay 5 -Quiet
} while (!$result)
```

And then use the value of the `$result` boolean to see if your computer is reponding again. [Test-Connection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849808.aspx) is a Cmdlet that cover the ping role.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want me to remove? Removing that part of the code and adding this would give me a invalid expression.

Comment: So JPBlanc i revised the entire script a little bit is this closer to what you where thinking i still have to test it.

Comment: So JPBlanc the way its setup now the first half of the script runs fine. Then during the ping process i get prompted for authentication with no credentials when i hit cancel i get the correct authentication box but does not finish the sequence correctly. The script makes the first break and then no longer works correctly for there.